# Why is there no consistency between how parameters are processed in DATEDIFF and TIMESTAMPDIFF in singlestore?

Tags: sql, datediff, singlestore, sql-date-functions

`SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, '2014-12-04', '2014-12-05') as DAYS_DIFF` returns `1`
,but `SELECT DATEDIFF('2014-12-04', '2014-12-05') as DAYS_DIFF` returns `-1`.

Why does `TIMESTAMPDIFF` do `date2-date1` whereas `DATEDIFF` does `date1-date2`?

Why does this inconsistency exist?

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: Single store. But it looks like this is also true for MySQL, https://database.guide/mysql-timediff-vs-timestampdiff-whats-the-difference/